# How to allow streaming of media file (Django server) in an iframe?

Tags: django, x-frame-options

I have a view that sends url of media file videos to an angular frontend.

This is the iframe that I use:

```
<iframe src="{{ video.video }}" frameborder="0" width="560" height="315"></iframe>
```

Here `video.video` contains the url:

```
http://192.168.1.84:8000/media/videos/ABC.mp4
```

The error shown is as follows:

```
Refused to display 'http://....mp4' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

The response headers are as follows:

```
Content-Length:6192325
Content-Type:video/mp4
Date:Thu, 23 Jul 2015 11:30:23 GMT
Last-Modified:Wed, 22 Jul 2015 13:15:43 GMT
Server:WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.6
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
```

I have tried to use `xframe_options_exempt` decorator in the view that sends the url but it displays the same error, I think it would not have worked anyway because the view just sends the url, the exempt must be applied to the GET request for the actual file to load in the iframe.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It appears you are serving the video file through the Django debug server. This is probably not a good idea: according to the docs, "this method is grossly inefficient and probably insecure", and will break when you turn DEBUG off. If you can serve the MP4 though a regular web server, you'll probably want to at some point. Incidentally, that will also solve this problem.

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned sorry, I am using the development server for now, so should I use nginx to serve the media file?

Comment: Yep! Having nginx serve it is faster, safer and all-around better. Also, because nginx supports ranges, you'll be able to search (move around in) the video without having to download all of it.